# Configurar websocket en PHP en mi VPS

Tags: php, socket, websocket

Hice un chat el cual usa un websocket con PHP, el problema es que en mi computador, funciona el socket normal, pero cuando lo subo a mi VPS el socket se ejecuta normalmente con el comando `php -q server.php` pero cuando me conecto desde el cliente, queda en estatus conectando hasta que da el timeout y no conecta, no entiendo por que.

Este es mi codigo, que estoy haciendo mal

```
<?php
// prevent the server from timing out
set_time_limit(0);

// include the web sockets server script (the server is started at the far bottom of this file)
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';

// when a client sends data to the server
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    // check if message length is 0
    if ($messageLength == 0) {
        $Server->wsClose($clientID);
        return;
    }

    //The speaker is the only person in the room. Don't let them feel lonely.
    if ( sizeof($Server->wsClients) == 1 )
        $Server->wsSend($clientID, "Cliente Unico");
    else
        //Send the message to everyone but the person who said it
        foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
            if ( $id != $clientID )
                $Server->wsSend($id, "$message");
}

// when a client connects
function wsOnOpen($clientID)
{
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) se ha conectado." );

    //Send a join notice to everyone but the person who joined
    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        if ( $id != $clientID )
            $Server->wsSend($id, "Usuario $clientID se ha unido a la sala.");
}

// when a client closes or lost connection
function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "Usuario $clientID se ha desconectado." );

    //Send a user left notice to everyone in the room
    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        $Server->wsSend($id, "Usuario $clientID ha abandonado la sala.");
}

// start the server

$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer("0.0.0.0", 9000);

?>
```

Ayuda, estoy desesperado

Comment: Abriste el puerto 9000 en el firewall?, si no sabes cómo, puedes solicitar al soporte de tu hosting que te ayuden.

Comment: si, abri el puerto 9000 y aun nada. Si creo que tendre que hacer eso a la final. :(

Comment: En mi experiencia localhost es 127.0.0.1, no 0.0.0.0 aunque sinceramente no se como funcione esa clase de PHPWebSocket

Comment: @abrahamhs, ciertamente debe ser la IP del servidor, asumo que la puso en ceros para no publicar la IP real.

Comment: Colocar la IP 0.0.0.0 significa que es accesible a traves de cualquier IP en el computador, tanto la local 127.0.0.1 como la publica o la del router si esta en una intranet, etc etc, igualmente, si pongo la publica es peor porque no me deja correrlo con la publica y me manda un error, y aun colocando 127.0.0.1 me ocurre lo mismo que colocando 0.0.0.0

Comment: https://alanchavez.com/la-diferencia-entre-0-0-0-0-y-127-0-0-1/

Comment: He leído el articulo, y si no sabía del 0.0.0.0 pero aún así los escenarios que describe para poder usar 0.0.0.0 me parecen muy distintos a los de este caso. Tal vez si colocas 127.0.0.1 y nos mandas el error que genera, podamos tener una pista para poder ayudarte

Comment: no genera ningun error colocando ni 0.0.0.0 ni 127.0.0.1

Comment: solo no conecta en el navegador cuando pongo mi ip publica, solo da error si le coloco la ip publica de mi vps

Comment: solo no conecta en el navegador cuando pongo mi ip publica, solo da error si le coloco la ip publica de mi vps